# Why does implementing the Cloneable Interface in a Kotlin class result in "error: no interface expected here"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface

I'm resuming work on an Android app that I haven't touched for a year. It used to build fine at the time. Now when I open it in Android Studio it complains that various libs, plugins, etc. are out of date. Trying to fix this myself, I couldn't get rid of all the sync/build errors, so in the end I updated Android Studio (from around 3.3, I think) to 3.5.2 and let it update whatever plugins etc. it wanted to.

Then I ran into issues indicating I should migrate from the old support packages to AndroidX (don't remember the details). To migrate, I then did the following:

- Set compileSdkVersion to 28 for all modules
- In all modules' build.gradle, updated the dependencies to 28
- Added android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true to gradle.properties
- Ran Refactor | Migrate to AndroidX...

Now Gradle sync works, but building fails with this error:

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: [...]\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\[...]\MyClass.java:9: error: no interface expected here
public final class MyClass extends java.lang.Cloneable {
                                           ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The above error is in generated code. My code, from which the above is generated, looks like this:

```
// MyClass.kt
class MyClass : Cloneable {
...
}
```

I understand `java.lang.Cloneable` is an interface, and the generated code has `extends` instead of `implements`. But as mentioned, this used to work, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I took another look at the project-level `build.gradle` and found it. Android Studio was suggesting to update the Kotline version again. I changed it to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
```

and now I can compile.